# Name of first ancestor

Tags: graph-theory

What is a good general name for the first ancestor / node in tree structures, like (a) in the tree below?

```
    c
   /
  b
 / \
a   d 
 \  
  c   f
   \ /
    e
     \
      g
```

Comment: "Root," maybe. I'm not sure what other sources say.

Comment: I'm by no means a graph theorist, but maybe the *root* of the tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In computer science (where trees are drawn top down) it is called the root. Since mathematically any vertex can serve as a root (it depends on how you draw the graph) I am not sure the term is used...